# Deploying a Node.js app using Juju

Tags: juju, nodejs

A little background. We are attempting to improve the deployment flow of our Node.js application, and decided to investigate Juju.

I am attempting to deploy a small practice express app (which does almost nothing) to a local Juju deployment using LXC.

I have worked my way through this https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/howto-node.html but when I attempt to change the repository that the node-app charm points at using this command,

```
juju set mark-app app_branch=https://github.com/markwithers/juju-test
```

the agent-state-info eventually changes to 'hook failed: "config-changed"'.

I've worked my way through several proposed soluition to this problem, some even from this site, but none appear to work in my case.

So, I then git cloned the node-app charm from here https://github.com/charms/node-app and placed it in ~/charms

I then edited the config.yaml in the charm to include the name of my github repository, and attempted to deploy from this local repository using the following command

```
juju deploy --repository=charms local:node-app
```

I get the following error message in my terminal

```
ERROR cannot get latest charm revision: charm not found in "/home/mark/charms": local:precise/node-app
```

Which doesn't make sense to me, as the repository is definitely in /home/mark/charms/node-app!

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake that I myself encountered when first starting out with juju.

You are missing the series identifier for the charm. Place the charm in `$HOME/charms/precise/node-app`

Deploy with

`juju deploy --repository=$HOME/charms local:node-app` and juju will deploy your charm from the local repository in $HOME as expected and stop fussing at you for not being able to find the charm.